# Performance difference between 'source-over' and 'destination-over' globalCompositeOperation for HTML canvas

Tags: html, canvas, globalcompositeoperation, 2d-context-api

Having reviewed the various [globalCompositeOperation options](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-global-composite-operations-tutorial/) for drawing on a 2D canvas, it occurs to me that `destination-over` is essentially the same as the default `source-over` but with the elements drawn in reverse.

I was wondering if anyone knows whether there's a performance difference between these two operations when the canvas calculates the composition and draws the pixels.

Comment: Have you tried to benchmark across various browsers: create a test in jsperf.com and paste the link to your friends

Comment: JSPerf is still down! I might just try both methods out myself and give it the eyeball test. I'll post my results soon.

Comment: Aaaaw crap... well that was expected as it was "too easy" to use

Comment: From my test case I couldn't observe any significant difference in performance with a naked eye. In case anyone is curious, for my test I was compositing ~5 1024x768 PNG images per frame onto a 1024x768 canvas with ~50 total similar image textures in memory, on an iPad. Both methods performed equally shakily! Reducing the amount of total image elements in memory brought the frame rate back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested I did set up a jsPerf to test this. According to my tests `source-over` is actually faster!

jsPerf test can be found here: http://jsperf.com/canvas-source-over-vs-destination-over/2